# Dynamic AND computed group by

Tags: r, data.table

Say, I have the below

```
# dummy data
df <- data.table(metric_1 = c(1,1,3)
                 , metric_2 = c(1,2,2)
                 ); df

   metric_1 metric_2
1:        1        1
2:        1        2
3:        3        2
```

and I wanted to loop through the 2 columns (real dataframe has many other columns) by carrying out a calculation (simplified below for illustration) on each column before doing a row count on each computed (group by) column:

```
# metric columns
x <- c('metric_1', 'metric_2')

# list to capture results
y <- vector('list', length(x))

# summarise
for (i in seq_along(x))
{
  y[[i]] <- df[, .(rows = .N)
               , by = .(fifelse(get(x[[i]]) == 1, 0, get(x[[i]])))
               ]
}
```

The above works as it gives a list of summaried tables:

```
> y
[[1]]
   fifelse rows
1:       0    2
2:       3    1

[[2]]
   fifelse rows
1:       0    1
2:       2    2
```

However, is it possible to within the loop, name the group by column? I tried the below using `x[[i]]`:

```
for (i in seq_along(x))
{
  y[[i]] <- df[, .(rows = .N)
               , by = .(x[[i]] = fifelse(get(x[[i]]) == 1, 0, get(x[[i]])))
               ]
}
```

but get the error:

```
Error: unexpected '=' in:
"    df[, .(rows = .N)
       , by = .(x[[i]] ="
```

A `data.table` solution would be appreciated given the amount of data.

Comment: Use new `env` argument instead of `get()`

Comment: This week......

Comment: @jangorecki
Could you give me a short line (of code) showing how to utilise `env` ?
or an URL for me to read on ?
Excited for this new way of specifying

Comment: Check new programming vignette on r-datatable.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `setNames(list(..), x[[i]])` in place of your `.(..)`.

```r
lapply(seq_along(x), function(i) {
  df[, .(rows = .N) ,
     by = setNames(list(fifelse(get(x[[i]]) == 1, 0, get(x[[i]]))), x[[i]]) ]
})
# [[1]]
#    metric_1  rows
#       <num> <int>
# 1:        0     2
# 2:        3     1
# [[2]]
#    metric_2  rows
#       <num> <int>
# 1:        0     1
# 2:        2     2
```

(FYI, we can't use `.( ... )` inside of `setNames`, it'll err with `could not find function "."`, likely due to parsing magic of NSE in `data.table` internals. This is not a problem, since `.(...)` is really just a convenience short-hand for `list(...)`.)

In general, `[`/`[[`-indexed variables can "never" work on the LHS of a simple `=` argument assignment. For that, `setNames` is the preferred way to go.

Comment: Just tried your solution. Always satisfying to find out.
Also thanks on the mentioning `indexed variables can "never" work on the LHS of a simple = `.
However, doesn't the `y[[i]] <- loop` in my 1st post count as object creation? Or was that merely storing in an object that already existed ?

Comment: Sorry, good clarification ... reworded, not sure what was going through my brain when I typed that. @SweepyDodo

Answer (score 4):

I suggest a different approach:

first melt to a long format, then calculate new values, and finally summarise (and/or split to list if needed)

**sample data**

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.table(metric_1 = c(1,1,3)
                 , metric_2 = c(1,2,2)
)

x <- c('metric_1', 'metric_2')
```

**code**

```
# convert to long
df.long <- melt(df, measure.vars = x)
# perfom action to get desired values
df.long[, valueNew := fifelse(value == 1, 0, value)]
# summarise
df.long[, .N, by = .(variable, valueNew)]
#    variable valueNew N
# 1: metric_1        0 2
# 2: metric_1        3 1
# 3: metric_2        0 1
# 4: metric_2        2 2

# if a list by x-column is needed
split(df.long[, .N, by = .(variable, valueNew)], by = "variable", keep.by = FALSE)
# $metric_1
#    valueNew N
# 1:        0 2
# 2:        3 1
# 
# $metric_2
#    valueNew N
# 1:        0 1
# 2:        2 2
```

Comment: True. This is apt for long pivot.
Tho would entail creating a sizeable df. May be a problem as at times the main df already close to filling my RAM.

I admit it most likely will be faster than the loop method.

Much appreciated !